# how to set custom sub domain only for Dynamic links and not for Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I had a main domain `example.com` hosted somewhere else. I had created two subdomains of it `app.example.com` and `link.example.com` and successfully mapped these to firebase hosting. Before I deployed firebase hosting those work perfectly for dynamic links.

But after my first deployment those are not working and showing this error

```
https://link.example.com is not connected properly
Your Dynamic Links path prefix is not configured in firebase.json. Check your firebase.json configuration and try again.
```

I want my `link.example.com` to only work for dynamic links and `app.example.com` for hosting (it is for my web app). But in the Firebase web console, there is no option to set this behavior. Any one please tell me how to set one of my sub domain only for dynamic links?